# Counting k-tuples

Tags: combinatorics

In this problem I need to answer the following question. 
Consider the set $S$ of all ordered k-tuples $A = (A_1,\ldots,A_k)$ of subsets of ${1,2,\ldots,n}$. Determine $$\sum_{A \in S} |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_k|$$. The hint they give me is the following: Depict $A$ by a $(0,1)$-matrix of size $k$ by $n$. To this matrix adjoin a 'special' row, namely the characteristic function of the union of the sets of A.Calculate the number of these $(0,1)$-matrices that have a 1 in a specified position in their 'special' row.

My approach was the following: Consider such a $(0,1)$ matrix A and also that the 'special row' will have an entry 1 if at least one of the entries in the column above such an entry has entry 1. So, to calculate the quantity desired, I will compute the total amount of possible such matrices, which would be $n*2^{nk}$ and substract the number of matrices where they have zeroes over a cretain number of rows, which would be $n*2^{k*(n-1)}$ Would this be the right approach for htis problem?

Comment: Should be $A_k$ instead of $A_n$?

Comment: You can use `\ldots` instead of periods to get proper spacing.

Comment: No, I think you made it worse. I think my correction was the correct one.

Comment: Don't you mean consider the set $S$ of all-ordered $k$-tuples $A = (A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_{\color{red}{k}})$ of subsets of $1, 2, \ldots, \color{red}{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you got to the factor $n$ (perhaps because I don't understand what you mean by a "total amount of matrices"), but your result is correct.

By symmetry, the sum over the sizes of the unions is $n$ times the number of times any given element occurs in the unions. There are $2^{kn}$ unions in all, and $2^{k(n-1)}$ unions in which a given element doesn't occur, so $2^{kn}-2^{k(n-1)}$ unions in which it does occur and thus a total of $n\left(2^{kn}-2^{k(n-1)}\right)$ elements in all the unions.